# Geo-location Mobile Development

Tags: android, java, mobile

I am new to programming and would like some advice on the best approach for tracking user location for IOS and Android.

My use case involves locational data of a user in relation to another user.

What I am failing to understand is how to get almost constant geolocational data, since Android APIs only allow location tracking every 15 mins (I'm assuming IOS is similar/stricter) - it looks like my only solution for almost constant `lat/long` tracking is with a foreground service.

I have been trying to think of a more creative way to track location without a foreground service and one was by creating background Geofences.

Specifically, if I create a geofence around a device, when the device leaves the fence I could destroy the original `on_exit` and create a new one around the device again and repeat. This way I can track the location of the device and also track which other users `enter/exit` the devices' geofence.

I'd be interested in hearing others ideas, or if anyone has a third party SDKs/packages that can help

Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask this...

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), [code fragments](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/904/185), best approaches etc.